# How to optimize this code? (Double loop in python, with an list)

Tags: python, loops, numpy, opencv, optimization

```
my_list = []
for x in range(len(imgbinary)):
    for y in range(len(imgbinary[0])):
        if imgbinary[x][y]==255 :
            my_list.append(imggray[x][y])

my_list.sort()
```

I want this code to be as fast as possible, I'm sure using numpy would be way better.

Answer (score 0):

Its only

```
my_list = imggray[imgbinary == 255]
```

the imgbinary == 255 generates the 2d array of booleans and then values are selected from the array
Also sort is useless since values are equal

Comment: I think you read too fast. It should be `mylist = imggray[imgbinary == 255]`.

Comment: But I need the values of imggray

Comment: I'll test this : "mylist = imggray[imgbinary == 255]"

Comment: oh ok imggray is there then

Comment: Hey, you are wrong when you say sort is useless since values are equal. It's grayscale image data, not binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `np.where`:

```
my_list = sorted(imggray[np.where(imgbinary==255)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you want to get the values of `imggray` in the pixel positions where `imgbinary` is equal to 255.

This should work fine without any loop used:

```
my_list = sorted(imggray[imgbinary ==255])
```

---

**Speed for 20 by 20 images:**

```
%timeit sorted(imggray[imgbinary ==255])
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
```